# How do I pass ID value of table in modal

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pass the id value of student in the modal form.  When I clicked the button 1stgrade, here is my table code:

```
<tbody>
<?php
require_once '../dbconfig.php';

$stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE role='student' AND gradelvl='7' AND sectionname='$_POST[table7]' ORDER BY lrnno ASC");
$stmt->execute();
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['fname']; ?></td>
```

and this is my modal form:

```
<td>
    <div align="center">
        <form action="studentprofilegradeaction.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
            <input type='text' name='id' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' />
            <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
            <a href="#1stgrade7"  class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-building"></i>1st</a>
            <!-- Modal HTML -->

            <div id="1stgrade7" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <input type='text' value='<?php echo $row['id'] ?>' />

                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h2 class="modal-title">Please Fill Correctly</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">1st Grading Result </h4>
                        </div>

                       <div class="modal-body">
                           <div align="left">
                                <b>Filipino:</b>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="c71stgfilipino" >
                           </div>
```

I want to pass the id number to modal 1stgrade.

Comment: `$_POST[table7]` is coming from where? that's a serious sql injection here also.

Comment: and did you close off the form with `</form>`?

Comment: ow sorry wait thats not included , wait while I reedited @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thats it can you help me with this ?

Comment: You have two modal-header. you must have just one.

Comment: Its ok to have two headers :) @amaia

Comment: hi help me please :( ? @Fred-ii-

Comment: you want $row['id'];  to  input named c71stgfilipino?

Comment: no , I just want to get the different id in table, so it will update the c71stgfilipino in just one id, but in my case , when I clicked the button 1stgrade7 only one id is being included, like id=1 is always posting in mymodal @Omi

Comment: its coming from here   SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE role='student' AND gradelvl='7' ORDER BY lrnno ASC  @amaia

Comment: Can I send my full code on your emails?

Comment: Sorry for my importunate questions, Because this is my 1st to make student managent system for a school , hope that youll he me all :)

Comment: does your userinfo table have different id for each record,please make sure you have set autoincrement for id column

Comment: yes its have a different id records, and its auto increment @Omi

Comment: i think your modal code is in forech when you hit btn it is always opening first modal coz of id is unique

Comment: I dont declare any foreach in there @Omi

Comment: Sorry i mean in loop you have while loop

Comment: I use while loop for table to paginate records @Omi

Comment: Does you modal code inside that loop?

Comment: No its Not @Omi

Comment: it should be, if not then how you are accessing $row['id'] inside modal, it should gives you error

Comment: Ow Sorry it its inside of while loop haha , my bad,  the enclosure of php is in the last of </form> ?> @Omi

Comment: so it is always giving you first modal so you are getting id 1 always

Comment: yes your right how can we solve this ? @Omi

Comment: left behind :( @Omi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your anchor tag:

```
<a href="#1stgrade7"  class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-building"></i>1st</a>
```

=>

```
<a id="openModal" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-building"></i>1st</a>
```

Remove other unnecessary code from your while loop, keep modal code outside the loop and give id to your id input inside modal:

```
<input id="userId" type='text' value='<?php echo $row['id'] ?>' />
```

Then you need jquery to read the od of clicked row and set it to modal write this after  :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#openModal").click(function() {

  //remove previous value
  $("#userId").val("");

  //this ll set id to your modal input
  $("#userId").val($(this).attr("data-id"));

  //open the modal
  $("#1stgrade7").modal("show");

 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this , wow how great your are having a perseverance for me, thaks a lot , but how can i auto paginate my modal into many if i keep modal code outside the loop ? @Omi

Comment: i m not getting exactly auto paginate your modal? just try the solution i think it wont matter.

Comment: Yes !!!!!!!! whohohoh thanks your code is very well passing the id value to its true owner , but my modal in table  displaying all the form haha , wait until I correct this @Omi

Comment: where can I declare my modal form ? in the top of your script ? @Omi

Comment: you can do that anywhere inside  <body></body> it wont matter

Comment: Whaha Im sorry for my importunate, ok ok I will try

Comment: I need to rest , Im so sleepy , will get back soon,

Comment: Hi Im back again, the "openModal" function doesnt work, is there any code or need to be declared inside my html ? @Omi

Comment: hi can you Omi can you help me with my another problem ?   How to disable <input “text”> if there is a value in column (inside moda)

Comment: if you have coulmn valune in php do like this  <input <?Php if($column!=null && !empty($column)?"disabled='disabled'"):"";?> >

Comment: hi please go to my problem link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148607/how-to-disable-input-text-if-there-is-a-value-in-column-inside-moda/43148679?noredirect=1#comment73375641_43148679  @Omi

Comment: did you got solution for above ^ problem

Comment: No any other solutions yet :( @Omi