# How to disable <input "text"> if there is a value in column (inside moda)

Tags: php

Hi GoodMorning(here in philippines) :)

```
    I want to disable the <input ="text"> if there is a value in the dedicated column

        <?php
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE role='student' AND gradelvl='7' AND sectionname='studid' ORDER BY lrnno ASC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
    ?>
    <form action="71stgmodalaction.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
        <div id="1stgrade7" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="form-group">      

    <input type='text' name='id' value='studid'; ?>' />
            <h2 class="modal-title"><div align="center">Please Fill Correctly</div></h2>

    <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title"><div align="center">1st Grading Result</div></h4>
              </div>

    <div class="modal-body"><div align="left">
        <b>Filipino:</b><input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" name="c71stgfilipino" >
    </div>           
    <div class="modal-footer">   
        <button type="submit" name="submit71st"  class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </form>
```

Here is my action to update column

```
 <?php

    if($_POST)
    {

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $c7finalgfilipino = $_POST['c7finalgfilipino'];     

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("UPDATE userinfo SET c7finalgfilipino=:qc7finalgfilipino WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":qc7finalgfilipino", $c7finalgfilipino);

    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);

    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        echo "Successfully updated";

    }
    else{
        echo "Query Problem";
    }
}

?>
```

How can I disable the **input type="text" name="c71sthfilipino"** if the is a value in that text ?

hope that will understand what Im saying, Im sorry for my english grammar :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi guys Im back again haha,@Omi @Fred-ii

Comment: Do you want to disable it as soon as the user types something in or do you want to populate it from the database and disable it if there is a value? You're currently not populating it from the db.

Comment: I want to disable when the user click the submit button , if there is no data inserted the text will not disable but if true the text will disable @mkaatman

Comment: @mkaatman can you help me with this ?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question. The way your code example is setup right now, the input field will never have a value after you submit.

Comment: sorry for my mistake,  @mkaatman

Comment: Guys please help !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You disable it like this

```
<input type="text" 
        class="resizedTextbox" 
        name="c71stgfilipino" 
<?php echo isset($row['column']) ? 'disabled' : '' ?> >
```

Comment: Ill try this  @media

Comment: where is the "column" come from ?

Comment: any other soluton please :)?

Comment: @Cassey27 see updated , also replace `column` with the name you need

Comment: What name ? my column name ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is JavaScript ([JQuery](https://jquery.com/) for making it easier).

```
$(function(){
   var elem = $('input[name="c71sthfilipino"]');
   if ( !$(elem).val() ){
      elem.prop('disabled', true);
   }
})
```

Comment: this code  wont work , it only works when the submit button was clicked

Comment: There is no reason for this to only work when submit was clicked. You have to place this code inside a `<script></script>` tag at the bottom of your `<body>` element, right before the `</body>` closing tag.